# How to sync configuration websphere to other site DR?

Tags: websphere

At this time, We've just build important system on Websphere Application ND 9.0.5.3. Our system is running at DC site, we also build DR enviroment with different name cellnames, hostname, IP, same cluster name, same server name, same packages application deploy. With Backend DB we found solution for repication DB, however with middleware I can't find solution to replicate Websphere.  Because of the complexity system, after tuning system with many configuration parameters, we may want to synchronize all applications, configuration on all profiles from DC site to DR site such as: JVM heapsize, JMS connection pool, Web container setting, thread pool , transaction setting ...
Please help us to meet this target or suggest us any 3rd tool to do these tasks ?

Comment: At my company we built a bunch of JACL scripts that build the environments.  This way we can create a new environment with the same parameters.  We can then install the same application on these environments and have high confidence it will run the same.  There are many reference objects in the WebSphere XML config files, it makes it difficult to just copy these around.

Comment: yeap, I search a lots on google, and I think the solution is script python , jacl... but I'm not good at coding. Do you have scripting that be able to get info and put updated value parameter for objects ?

Comment: Hi, I made a mistake.  Jython should be used now, not JACL.  JACL works only on old versions.  For samples, you can look at https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1004_gibson/1004_gibson.html or any other site you will find on IBM ex https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/txml_7libserver.html

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it. Some people suggest me focus on properties of nodes, server with command  AdminTask.extractConfigProperties then apply to DR's enviroment. How do you think about it ?

Comment: **If** you are using WAS Network Deployment, you should apply properties to the entire cell.  I avoid modifying anything directly on nodes.

Comment: Yes, I'm using WAS ND version. But DR and DC site has a different cellnames, hostnames so can't apply to whole cell. Only ServerName, clusterName is the same name, so I assume using AdminTask.extractConfigProperties for each cluster to export config properties then bring it to DR and apply to DR'cluster. Is it safe ?

Comment: I have not done WAS admin for a little while, this extractConfigProperties is very nice!  Indeed you could use it.  I especially like the variables (`!{cellName}`) that allow you to adapt the configurations on the restore.  I would say try it out!

Comment: thanks Nic. I'm going to read details about it